# fork is giving weird output when trying to add variable from child to father after killing child in c

Tags: c, arrays, linux, fork

I have this weird problem with a program on which I create 2 processes with a `fork();` then i search an array for a specific value entered by the user. in a test version I search for the value 6 in this array.

> int vet[max]={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0,6};

so the output is:

```
ci sono 2 di 6
ci sono 1 di 6
```

here is my output statement: `printf("ci sono %i di %i\n",l+j,k);` (l is the child variable, j is the father variable and k is the number to search)

but I close the child process with a `wait(&status);` and did the output afterwards. Is there a way to combine the two variables of the different processes and output them together.

here is the full code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>         //Fork
#include <sys/wait.h>       //wait
#include <sys/types.h>      //getpid
#include <time.h>
#define max 20

int main(){
    int i,k,l=0,j=0,pid;
    int status;
    int vet[max]={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0,6};
    //srand(time(NULL));
    //for(i=0;i<max;i++){
    //  vet[i]=rand()%100+1;
    //}
    printf("Inserire il valore da trovare: ");
    scanf("%i",&k);
    pid=fork();
    if(pid<0){
        printf("ERRORE\r\n");
        return 0;
    }
    if(pid==0){
        for(i=0;i<max/2;i++){
            if(vet[i]==k){
                l++;                
            }
        }
        //printf("trovati figlio %i\n",l);
        wait(&status);
    }else{
        for(i=max/2;i<max;i++){
            if(vet[i]==k){
                j++;                
            }
        }
    }
    printf("ci sono %i di %i\n",l+j,k);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: You need shared memory to do this. Use threads instead.

Comment: @EdHeal our teacher said to use the `fork();` statement

Comment: The variables `l` and `j` are local in the memory space of each single forked process, then the "0 pid process" doesn't see the `j` the "!0 pid process" evaluated and the "!0 pid process" doesn't see the `l` the "0 pid process" evaluated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not really orthodox but you could do this:

```
if(pid!=0){
    for(i=0;i<max/2;i++){
        if(vet[i]==k){
            l++;                
        }
    }
    //printf("trovati figlio %i\n",l);
    wait(&j);
    j = WEXITSTATUS(j);
}else{
    for(i=max/2;i<max;i++){
        if(vet[i]==k){
            j++;                
        }
    }
    return j;
}
```

Comment: doesn't the `wait(&j)` have to be in the father process?

Comment: can we also switch it with `the return j`

Comment: gives `ci sono 0 di 6` when there have to be: `ci sono 3 di 6` (there are 3 sixses)

Comment: I thought that is what you want